# Using IF statements for addressing things related to XML

Tags: c#, xml

When I try to tell the IF command to check if something is equivalent to a value that is in an XML file, the IF command does not allow you to do that.

This code is the one that reads the XML file:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class ReadXML : MonoBehaviour
{

   // Use this for initialization
   void Start()
   {

     List<Dictionary<string, string>> allTextDic = parseFile();
     Dictionary<string, string> dic = allTextDic[0];

   }

   public List<Dictionary<string, string>> parseFile()
   {
      TextAsset txtXmlAsset = Resources.Load<TextAsset>("riddles");
      var doc = XDocument.Parse(txtXmlAsset.text);

      var allDict = doc.Element("document").Elements("row");
      List<Dictionary<string, string>> allTextDic = new 
      List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
      foreach (var oneDict in allDict)
      {
         var twoStrings = oneDict.Elements("string");
         XElement element1 = twoStrings.ElementAt(0);
         XElement element2 = twoStrings.ElementAt(1);
         string first = element1.ToString().Replace("<string>", 
         "").Replace(" 
         </string>", "");
         string second = element2.ToString().Replace("<string>", 
         "").Replace("</string>", "");

         Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
         dic.Add("1", first);
         dic.Add("2", second);

         allTextDic.Add(dic);


     }

     return allTextDic;

  }

}
```

And here is the XML file :

```
<document>
 <row>
   <string>1</string >
   <string>2</string >
 </row>
 <row>
   <string>3</string >
   <string>4</string >
</row>
<row>
   <string>5</string >
   <string>6</string >
</row>
<row>
   <string>7</string >
   <string>8</string >
</row>

</document>
```

Ok, here is my problem. When you see this script on Visual Studio, the line that says "dic" below has a red curvy line under it. Why is that so? dic["1st"] has the same value as 1 but the API doesn't allow to do it that way, so how can we fix?

```
public GameObject obj;
private void OnMouseDown()
{
    if (dic["1st"] == 1)
    {
        Instantiate(obj);
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Using a single `=` operator is **assignment**. using two `==` is **comparison**. What you want is comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Be carefull with `==` operator ; try :

```
public GameObject obj;
private void OnMouseDown()
{
    if (Convert.ToInt32(dic["1st"]) == 1)
    {
        Instantiate(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does, please do not just add code as an answer without explanation.

Comment: Although your answer probably solves the problem, please explain what it does/changes for OP to learn.

Comment: Can i please get more information about the script?